# Finding integral solution to $3^a-3^b=2(3^c-3^d)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove that there doesn't exist a solution for integers a,b,c,d $\geq 1$  such that $3^a-3^b=2(3^c-3^d)$ with $a \neq b$ and $c \neq d$.

I have no idea how to start such problems. Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  If you had such a solution, what happens if you divide both sides of the equation by $3$?

Comment: If (a,b,c,d) is a solution so is (a-1,b-1,c-1,d-1) and so on till we reach (a-d,b-d,c-d,0). Now we have $3^p-3^q=2.3^r-2$. LHS is multiple of 3 but RHS aint. SO not possible. Right.

Comment: @Umakant Well, you still need to look further when $b = d$. Then you have $3^p-1 = 2(3^r-1)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, that would give me $3^p-2.3^r+1=0$. Taking $3^r=x$ and $p-r=s$ we have $(3^s-2)x+1=0$ Hence no integral solution.